# Wired connection in place but no internet

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have looked in askubuntu and elsewhere with no luck.

Old computer 18.04 Desktop (wired) working fine also WiFi to phone.
New computer, using Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop, internet doesn't work. The 20.04 Desktop was installed from a USB stick.

I have booted again from the same USB to 'Try Ubuntu' and that is working fine both for Wired and Wi-Fi separately.
When installed a month or so ago the internet worked for both Wired and Wi-Fi.

Now Network wired shows 'connected' and (WiFi appears to connect) but no internet in either case (tested separately).

ping 8.8.8.8 fails (IP address for google.com).

pinging my own IP address does work (from running `ip address`)
Not sure what 'pinging router' other than 'own ip address' means. I don't have a LAN as such.

I am mainly concerned to use the wired connection.

Further to waltinator's suggestion (very long; 2x<warn>, 1x 'Error:' at second <warn>:

> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <**warn**>  [1641634066.9519] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <**warn**>  [1641634067.2118] **Error**: failed to open /run/network/ifstate

The full output:

> pm@pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager

> [sudo] password for pm:

> -- Logs begin at Mon 2021-11-15 11:41:56 GMT, end at Sat 2022-01-08 09:30:01 GMT. --
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.8203] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.8204] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globall-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.8660] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.8685] manager[0x558564507010]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.8685] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9440] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9441] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX"
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9443] dns-mgr[0x5585644ec290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9447] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.2/0000:03:09.0/0000:06:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9448] manager[0x558564507010]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set disabled
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9448] manager[0x558564507010]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9468] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9481] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9487] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9498] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9508] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9509] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi disabled by radio killswitch; disabled by state file
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9510] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9511] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9511] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9517] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9517] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9517] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <warn>  [1641634066.9519] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9562] device (lo): carrier: link connected
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9563] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9569] manager: (eno1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
> Jan 08 09:27:46 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634066.9575] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.1938] device (wlp6s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.1943] manager: (wlp6s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.1952] device (wlp6s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.1974] manager: (pvpnksintrf0): new Dummy device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2110] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <warn>  [1641634067.2118] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2136] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2153] modem-manager: ModemManager available
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2154] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2154] policy: auto-activating connection 'pvpn-killswitch' (10fcf63c-017f-4912-813b-b8b7c9439e35)
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2158] device (pvpnksintrf0): Activation: starting connection 'pvpn-killswitch' (10fcf63c-017f-4912-813b-b8b7c9439e35)
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2158] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2161] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2163] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2165] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: ((src/nm-ip4-config.c:2405)): assertion '' failed
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: ((src/nm-ip4-config.c:2405)): assertion '' failed
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2171] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2186] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2187] device (pvpnksintrf0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2190] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2195] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2196] policy: set 'pvpn-killswitch' (pvpnksintrf0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2197] policy: set 'pvpn-killswitch' (pvpnksintrf0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2200] device (pvpnksintrf0): Activation: successful, device activated.
> Jan 08 09:27:47 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634067.2203] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1924] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1926] device (eno1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1933] policy: auto-activating connection 'Profile 1' (26c703ce-1b00-42d8-93e5-2aae14681f27)
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1937] device (eno1): Activation: starting connection 'Profile 1' (26c703ce-1b00-42d8-93e5-2aae14681f27)
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1938] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1942] device (eno1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1947] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:50 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634070.1950] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4560] dhcp4 (eno1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '86400'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name          => 'home'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option expiry               => '1641720472'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option host_name            => 'pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.153'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option next_server          => '192.168.1.1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4561] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_routers    => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4562] dhcp4 (eno1): option wpad                 => '
> '           \             <br/>
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4563] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4575] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4595] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4597] device (eno1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4610] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
> Jan 08 09:27:52 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634072.4615] manager: startup complete
> Jan 08 09:27:54 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634074.6730] dhcp6 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
> Jan 08 09:27:54 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634074.6773] dhcp6 (eno1): option dhcp6_name_servers   => '2001:8b0::2020 2001:8b0::2021'
> Jan 08 09:27:54 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634074.6774] dhcp6 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
> Jan 08 09:28:28 pm-B550-AORUS-PRO-AX NetworkManager[899]: <info>  [1641634108.5113] agent-manager: agent[451fafce680ed289,:1.83/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1385843/edit) to clarify: Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop or Ubuntu 20.04 Server? Can you ping your router? Can you ping anything else on your LAN? Does "*Live from USB on the new machine is working fine*" mean that you tested wired and wireless networking in the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment and both worked properly?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.